# What type of formats/settings should I use in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design

I have a series of graphics that I got produced by a graphic designer for my website and I am wondering what format/settings i should use when converting the `.ai` files into `JPEG`, `PNG`, `GIF` files.

I have the following types of files

- Logos **(Requires transparency)**
- Avatar like images for the brand.
- Banners
- Background Graphics

Being that it's for a website, I obviously want quality but also small file size to help keep the site fast.

---

#### Logos

As the logo requires transparency `PNG` format is the best choice.

Questions:

1. What would be better between `PNG-8` and `PNG-24`?
2. If `PNG-8`, what would be better between selective, adaptive, perceptual, restrictive?
3. If `PNG-8` or `PNG-24`, should I apply interlacing to the images?
4. If `PNG-8`, what would be better out of diffusion, pattern, noise or no dither?
5. What type of image optimization should I be using, art optimization, type optimization or no optimization?

#### Avatar like images, banners, background graphics

Questions:

1. What would be better between `PNG-8` and `PNG-24`, `GIF` and `JPEG`?
2. If `PNG-8` what would be better between selective, adaptive, perceptual, restrictive?
3. If `PNG-8`, `PNG-24` or `GIF`, should I apply interlacing to the images?
4. If `PNG-8` or `GIF`, what would be better out of diffusion, pattern, noise or no dither?
5. What type of image optimization should I be using, art optimization, type optimization or no optimization?

Comment: See [What web graphics formats to use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-web-graphics-formats-to-use)

Comment: also see [how do I ask a good question?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is broad, since you're looking for a very detailed explanation without relating to a specific problem. What have you tried that didn't work and why? In any case, to point you in the right direction:

1. The designer should have delivered these for you if he got paid for the service. It's not the client's job to understand these things.
2. You're overthinking it. The `PNG-24` preset should work for all your items with default settings. For larger banners the `JPG High` preset could be better if you need to keep the file size down. `GIF` is not so popular anymore, ignore it.
3. Everything else is not so relevant unless there's a problem with the above, in which case show us what you have and what the actual problem is.
4. Also see [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-saving-artwork-for-web.html), [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/best-practices-creating-web-graphics.html) or [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/7992/62949).

Comment: I have just been producing loads of copies of banners in all of the variations I can think off, compared them all and if I go through and look for differences at max quality (where I can't tell the difference) and they look like the .AI file's quality. `JPEG 90%` comes out at 101KB, `PNG-8` comes out at 42KB, `PNG-24` comes out at 76KB, `GIF` comes out at 55KB. As for transparent images, I notice a noticeable difference around the outer edges between `PNG-8` and `PNG-24` with the latter looking better.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing it right. A few KB more or less is not much of a difference nowadays. Go with whatever looks best.